# How to find out the document is password protected in Libre office command?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I was working to convert some documents into PDF and I used libre office 4.0 for this, the command I used for this is,

```
"E:\LibreOffice 4.0\program\soffice.exe\" --convert-to pdf inputfile.xlxs --outdir PDFs/outputfile.pdf --headless
```

the above command works for the document like xlsx but when the document is password protected and password is unknown, it does not work. I would like to know before run this command that the input document is password protected?

can any one help me out...

Comment: Does this have anything to do with PHP/Programming?

Comment: No, but the commands are executing in PHP only on windows server, that's why I tag php